# Android Studio 2.0 doesn't show emulators and devices

Tags: android-studio

Yesterday, I downloaded the new Android Studio 2.0. When I run the project the Deployment Target is empty. I can't see neither my device nor the Genymotion's emulator. I tried to disable and enable the ADB Integration, and to kill and start the adb again but with no luck. When I type `adb devices` I can see and the device and the emulator. Is this a bug from Android Studio 2.0 or I made something wrong on the install?

Comment: if you already create emulator with previous version, delete them and create new. Wonder why device is not detectable !

Comment: no the emulator is new. The device is detectable. I want to say that when I have plugged in the device, I accepted the USB debugging with the RSA key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I open the logcat, it throw this message

> Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to
>   detect adb version, adb output:
>   /home/vassilis/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1:
>   /home/vassilis/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: "("
>   unexpected

So I download again platfomr tools https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip and replaced them on Android/Sdk

now it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because Genymotion is used with outdated Android tools.

To solve this, follow the following steps.

1. open Genymotion app
2. go to Settings -> ADB
3. select 'Use custom Android SDK tools'
4. Select location of your SDK.

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem at the moment alot of mac andoid studio users are facing and according to android help it will be solved in android 2.0.2 update.

Comment: I don't think that this is Android Studio problem. Today I faced the same error because I installed the Android Studio again. The problem is on the `adb` file from platform tools. When I download the platform tools from the URL given on the above comment and replace the `adb` file, the error disappeared.